# How to make stick change angle after pressure is added?

Tags: structural-engineering

I am currently trying to create a small product with my 3D printer.

The product consists of a flat wide stick first, which then is connected to a 45 degrees angled stick. What I now want to achieve is that the 45 degree angled plate gets to the same level as the flat plate when pressure gets added. So it goes from 45 degrees to 0 looking something like this:

[image]

I have been doing a bit of googling and came across something called a torsion spring which I assume could work pretty well looking like this:
[image]

However, I do not currently own a torsion spring at home and I assume torsion springs cannot be made using a 3D printer. I was wondering if there is an optional solution for this task?

Comment: Your 3D printer prints in plastic, right? Which is presumably bendy to some extent (engineering.SE *loves* technical terms like "bendy"). If you want to make it bend at a particular point, why not make the plate thinner at that point. It would look something like a [mesnager hinge](https://www.google.co.uk/search?site=&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=784&bih=639&q=mesnager+hinge&oq=mesnager&gs_l=img.3.1.0l2j0i30k1l5j0i5i30k1l3.176.1170.0.2710.9.9.0.0.0.0.149.719.6j2.8.0....0...1ac.1.64.img..1.8.714.0.l8yoKOs-tms#spf=461). You may need to experiment with varying thickness to get the stiffness you want.

Comment: Yeah I print with PLA. Ok I will look that up! Thanks for the tip. Would a hinge also automatically push down to 45 degrees after you release the pressure or would you need to push it down to 45 degrees yourself? That is why a spring would be nice because it would constantly pull down when pressure is not being added

Comment: how many cycles does it need to flex.

Comment: So long as it's adequately made (not too thin), the hinge would return to (or almost to) its original position. However, this also depends on how frequently this piece would have to move, because fatigue (failure due to repeated use) would be a serious problem here.

Comment: @agentp What is cycles? I am a bit new to this area so pardon me!

Comment: @Wasabi Okay alright. There are several hinge files out there to 3d print so I am gonna try it out right away!

Comment: @CarlosRodrigez - Depends on whether you go past yield when you apply the pressure, i.e. whether you go beyond elastic behaviour into plastic behaviour. That will depend on the material used (does it exhibit elastic behaviour? and what is its yield?) and also on how thin/thick the hinge part is.

Comment: @CarlosRodrigez "What is cycles?" - How many times do you want it to flex back and forth? If you want something that will work reliably 1,000 or 1,000,000 times, that is a bigger challenge than something that only needs to work 5 or 10 times without breaking. Actually, there are plastics that would work 1,000,000 times, (e.g. Delrin) but I don't think they are "printable" - you would have to assemble the 3-d-printed parts and the "hinge" somehow.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on 3dprinting.se

Comment: If you take a look at thingiverse.com or myminifactory you can find a number of plans for items with a builtin spring (i.e. printed).  There's a much smaller elastic limit than for metal parts, as is true of any plastic item.